# In Iron Man 2, why doesn't Whiplash's whip cut into the racetrack asphalt as well?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, marvel, iron-man-2

In *Iron Man 2*, when Whiplash strikes the cars on the racetrack with his plasma weapon, why doesn't it cut into the racetrack asphalt, given it cuts through the cars so easily?

Comment: Who says it didn't? And even if it did, perhaps it wasn't sufficiently enough to show up on camera or not enough for the special effects team to make the considerable effort for the lash marks to show up. We are expected to believe Whiplash's whips were sufficiently capable of damaging the concrete. OR. We could say they were specifically designed to damage only metal objects (which would make perfectly good sense considering the weapon was designed for Iron Man) and was shown to slice through an automobile quite easily.

Comment: That's pretty laughable, because you can clearly see they don't if you watch the movie. And they're not "specifically designed to damage only metal objects". It apparently cuts also carbon fiber and plastic, as well as various metal alloys in the F1 car. It would undoubtedly cut into asphalt, as well as the ground.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume he can adjust the whips' power levels. They idle in look-badass mode, but when he wants to slice a car, he pushes the "purée" button.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**They *do* cut through the asphalt.**

Throughout the scene, if you pay close attention, you can see that the whips have an effect on the asphalt.

Here, when Whiplash first reveals his whips, they burn the ground.
[image: Whiplash on race track]
The arrows point to the darkened streaks where the whips burned the ground.

In this next still, we can see that there is some destruction to the asphalt between Tony's legs.
[image: Whiplash almost castrates Tony Stark]
Notice the rocky appearance outside the whip mark? That's the crumbling asphalt.

Here's another shot of Whiplash doing nothing *but* damaging the track as he approaches Tony in a flurry of whipping.
[image: Whiplash approaches Tony for an attack]
You can see the scorch and cut marks easily, but I highlighted them with more arrows.

**So why aren't there marks after he attacks the cars?**

I think there are three very plausible reasons we don't see the whips make marks beneath the cars:

1. Force needs to be applied *to* the asphalt in order to do more than scorch it. The crumbling effect seen between Tony's legs only happens when Whiplash forcefully strikes towards the ground. When using a whip, the force is applied only until the whip hits its "target". If that target is above something, such as the ground, then the whip will merely "fall" the rest of the way to the ground. **Whiplash is aiming only low enough to ensure he cuts through the cars, but still high enough to not forcefully strike the ground.**
2. Although the whips cut through the cars like a hot knife through butter, it may be possible for Whiplash to feel *some* resistance as the whips slice through. Looking at the scene, it also appears that Whiplash pulls/curls the whips away immediately after they've cut through the cars (both the first car and Tony's). **Whiplash is highly skilled at using his whips, and when he detects that they stop meeting resistance he retracts them (before they cut into the ground).**
3. The scene cuts very quickly from shot to shot, and the shots usually don't give visual coverage of the same angle or area twice. Since we know that the cuts *do* happen sometimes, we can assume that they happen *every* time. **The cuts and camera angles change too quickly and inconsistently for us to get a good visual confirmation.**

Comment: An excellent answer with some very well chosen screen shots. You have my +1